# 'tailwindcss' is not recognized as an internal or external command on windows 10 laptop

Tags: node.js, windows, node-modules, tailwind-css

I have an identical directories with TAILWIND CSS project both on desktop compute and laptop computer.

On desktop computer it initializes and works well, but I can't force make it run on laptop computer.

Both machines have WIN10 (desktop->professional ver. and laptop->home edition) and also both have installed same version of node -> 18.7.0 and also same version on VS CODE.

Both project folder, i.e. *node_modules* folder, *package.json*, *package-lock.json* and *tailwind.config.js* files and project files itself are fully identical (I've checked it intentionally with 3rd party software).

When I try to run tailwind to watch on laptop I get this error:

```
npm run watch-css

> tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/styles.css --watch

'tailwindcss' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried:

1. Re-initialized project -> delete *node_modules* folder and run `npm install` again.
2. Re-initialized project from scratch -> remove *node_modules*, *package.json* and *package-lock.json* files, then:

   ```
   npm init -y 
   npm install -D tailwindcss 
   npx tailwindcss init
   ```

and at that point I had the same error:

```
'tailwindcss' is not recognized as an
internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

3. Reinstall node.js on laptop
4. Change version of node.js
5. Rename existing project
6. Initialize a new project with a new name and new folder

Nothing helped yet.

In all cases npm refuses to find path to

```
C:\Users\...\CODE\HTML-CSS\tailwind\node_modules\.bin
```

where the tailwind scripts are installed.

Comment: I don’t know if it is a copy paste mistake, but if you are entering the commands as they are in your question, it is clear that it will not work. It should be: 
`npm init -y`
Then: 
`npm install -D tailwindcss`
And then:
`npx tailwindcss init`

Comment: yes, of course it text edit mistake, corrected